# jQuery click function on an array of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input, onchange

I try to implement a change function on every input field named plz_von.

```
<input type="text" name="plz_von[]" class="plz_von" placeholder="10000">
<input type="text" name="plz_von[]" class="plz_von" placeholder="20000">
<input type="text" name="plz_von[]" class="plz_von" placeholder="30000">
<input type="text" name="plz_von[]" class="plz_von" placeholder="40000">
```

I want to do it this way:

```
$('input[name="plz_von[]"]').change(function() {
  alert("got it");
});
```

I don't know what's going wrong. Any idea? I tried it with the class name as well.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. http://jsfiddle.net/Cb7qp/

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Open your console and check for errors

Comment: Hi adeneo! I see it works, but I find no errors in the console regarding this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the support. Finally I found the failure.

I had to put the jQuery code into the ready function! This is quite clear, because the function cannot by added to the inputfield, when the input field isn't already loaded in the DOM.. *grrr*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="plz_von[]"]').change(function() {
            alert("hu");
    });
});
```

Best regards,
 Marco

Answer (score 0):

Because [ ] is an attribute selector. You need to escape it.

```
 $('input[name="plz_von\\[\\]"]')
```

Since you have a class that is common, you might as well use that instead.

```
 $('input.plz_von')
```